# Possibilities of a countdown Timer - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is it possible for a countdown timer to be activated whilst in the method of a button and keep running even though a web page is refreshed? I have tried to implement a countdown timer that is activated when a button is clicked but when the web page is refreshed, the timer keeps on running alright but it doesn't show in the web page. So when the user presses the button again, the timer is restarted again including the previous time it left off. Can someone explain? I have posted more than I can count but no one is helping.

**Edit;** 
With this code, the timer runs perfectly but doesn't update to the span element when the page is refreshed, button doesn't restart the timer when the timer runs out and it's freaking annoying! Also, the button doesn't remain disabled when the page is refreshed.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLmeagLo/

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#coinbtn1");
var label = document.querySelector("#countdown1");
var timer;
var countdown = localStorage.getItem("countdown") || 60;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var coinRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users_coins').child(uid).child('coins');
  var counter = 50;
  coinRef.transaction(function(counter) {
    return (counter || 0) + 50;
  });

  if (!timer) {
    countdown = 10;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = true;
      countdown--;
      label.innerText = countdown + "s";
      localStorage.setItem("countdown", countdown);
      if (countdown <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('coinbtn1').disabled = false;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
  <div>Timer : <span id="countdown1">05:00</span></div>
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <button id="coinbtn1" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">50 coins</button>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One reason you might not be getting any help is you aren't showing any code. This site is for help with specific code issues.  As your questions sits now the answer is "yes", but without an idea of what you've tried or the direction you're going, no one can really help.

Comment: Don't say what you don't know. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928320/timer-refreshes-upon-page-reload  I got no help!

Comment: You didn't post any code here.

Answer (score 1):

you could probably attach that behavior to a new Date() and a variable inside of localStorage. Kind of isTimerActive =  true, initialTime = (whenever your button was clicked).  and just check update the values on window load (check for isTimerActive, if it is, then update counter based on initialTime + new Date() in whatever unit you need it).

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I did something similar and I didn't reach any result. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928320/timer-refreshes-upon-page-reload

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variables can't persist between page (re)loads, so you need some form of persistence.  There's various ways to tackle this depending on your needs:

- **Store in URL** - You can make the page take in the countdown goal as a fragment (eg. `page.html#20181111-035625` where timestamp goal could be your end time in seconds, miliseconds or as a date-time representation (be careful with `:` and spaces).  When the user presses the button, you re-direct them to the page with the correct fragment added.

  **Pros:** The goal time can be shared as a URL. Simple to implement. Supported even in ancient browsers, not cleared by clearing local storage / closing the browser.

  **Cons:** The user only sees the same countdown if they (re)open the same URL, so closing the window and re-navigating to the base page loses the countdown. User can be misled with the wrong countdown by being given the wrong URL

---

- **SessionStorage or LocalStorage** - The former persists until the browser is closed, the later will last through the browser being closed.

  **Pros:** Not tied to URL.  Widely supported on anything relevant (be careful of really old browsers, like IE < 8)

  **Cons:** Tied to a specific browser/device/origin. If your user opens the page on another device, they will not see their timer.

---

- **Server-side storage** - Store the timer goal / state on some form of persistent backend (database, etc)

  **Pros:** Persists across devices/browsers/sessions. Most robust as far as the user not being misled with fake timers.

  **Cons:** Most complex, requires some form of session/account feature on the backend

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are stateless. Every time you load a web page, it's as if it's the first time that the browser sees it. So when you reload your page, the browser has no memory of the previous countdown, and all variables are reinitialized.

To make the countdown stateful, you need to store its value between calls. A simple way to do that is to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which is a key-value store that each web page gets from the browser. You can put a value in it with:

```
localStorage.setItem('countdown', countdown);
```

And then get it on reload with:

```
var countdown = localStorage.getItem('countdown');
```

A simple example of a countdown timer with this:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var label = document.querySelector("span");
var timer;
var countdown = localStorage.getItem("countdown") || 60;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!timer) {
    countdown = 10;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      countdown--;
      label.innerText = countdown+"s";
      localStorage.setItem("countdown", countdown);
      if (countdown <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert("All done");
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<span>60s</span>
<button>Start countdown</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. But I included what you are saying. And it still didn't work. No one was responding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928320/timer-refreshes-upon-page-reload

Comment: Please help as it is a school project I am working on.

Comment: Two people provided answers on this question within 10 minutes of you posting it. If you're having trouble making this work, I recommend that you post the [minimal code that shows what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read that link please, it is quite useful).

Comment: They did provided answers but they were very vague.

Comment: That's not a reason to repost the same question multiple times. Work with the person who is already trying to help you. I just clicked through that chain of posts to find that 6 hours ago Niek gave you essentially the same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926194/timer-refreshes-after-browser-page-is-reloaded-javascript

Comment: The answer Niek gave didn't help. He doesn't deserve the upvote.

Comment: Also, I did try working with him but he just went off. Not like I didn't.

Comment: Did you try the code I gave you? What didn't work about it for you? Can you reproduce the problem with that code in a site like jsbin/jsfiddle, so that we can have a look at it?

Comment: Currently trying it. A moment.

Comment: I have tried your method Frank. But the thing is after refreshing, the timer isn't refreshed but it doesn't show to the user. It gives me the text I used html as so <span  id="countdown1">05:00</span>....Please help.

Comment: Yeah, my code only starts the timer on a click. It doesn't start the timer yet when it loads a value from the local storage. You'll have to add that. Note that the code you now shared is a lot more complex, in ways that don't relate to the problem at hand: maintaining a variable across page reloads. I'd remove anything that is not related to that when asking for help.